# Cannot share file from app own external storage (SDcard) folder in Android 11

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider, scoped-storage

My app has sharing functionality that stopped working in Android 11, and I don't know why. It works perfectly for any Android <= 10. My app targets API 29 to try not to fall into scoped storage problems. Sorry if this is well known by now, but I am basically ignorant regarding scoped storage.

The app folder in the external sdcard is `/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/`. Inside this folder I have a bunch of other folders.

If I try to share the file `/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv`, say via WhatsApp, the file is not sent, and this is the logcat (>=Warn):
**(EDIT: It seems I can share the file if it is inside the `files/` folder?!)**

```
18:26:08.468 15827-15827/? W/adbd: timeout expired while flushing socket, closing
18:26:09.472 803-1100/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.floritfoto.apps.ave/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser$_13168#1](id:323000009a3,api:0,p:-1,c:803) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
18:26:09.472 13168-14775/com.floritfoto.apps.ave W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x708d001ec0 disconnect failed
18:26:09.495 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:26:09.498 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:26:09.501 1117-1257/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Tried to set launchTime (0) < mLastActivityLaunchTime (53651559)
18:26:09.504 1117-1257/? W/WindowManager: Execute app transition: mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_ACTIVITY_OPEN, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.executeAppTransitionForAllDisplay:2586 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.reportResumedActivityLocked:2225 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.completeResumeLocked:5646 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.minimalResumeActivityLocked:1212 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked:1135
18:26:09.512 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Ignoring intent's EXTRA_TITLE, deprecated in P. You may wish to set a preview title by using EXTRA_TITLE property of the wrapped EXTRA_INTENT.
18:26:09.512 1117-1379/? W/PkgPredictorService: background app without no launcher icon android for.uid: 1000 userId: 0
18:26:09.513 5471-5471/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.android.app.sharestar.ShareStarProvider
18:26:09.560 1117-3258/? E/IntervalStats: Unable to parse usage stats package 1041
18:26:09.560 1117-3258/? E/IntervalStats: Unable to parse usage stats package 1520
18:26:09.560 1117-3258/? E/IntervalStats: Unable to parse usage stats package 1997
18:26:09.618 13168-14876/com.floritfoto.apps.ave E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv from pid=5471, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:841)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:758)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:684)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
18:26:09.618 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
18:26:09.619 2498-3360/? W/NearbySharing: Ignore registering DIRECT_SHARE_SERVICE send surface, due to disabled scanning mediums. [CONTEXT service_id=194 ]
18:26:09.619 2498-3360/? W/NearbySharing: NearbySharingService call registerSendSurface returned nonzero status code for calling package com.google.android.gms: STATUS_DISABLED [CONTEXT service_id=194 ]
18:26:09.643 1117-1145/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{a0df760 u0 com.floritfoto.apps.ave/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5183 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5164 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5570 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:332 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6035 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$dwJG8BAnLlvKNGuDY9U3-haNY4M.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:112
18:26:09.668 5471-5471/? W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.internal.widget.RecyclerView{d6a7c8a VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1289,1011 #102047e android:id/resolver_list} during layout: running second layout pass
18:26:09.671 13168-14876/com.floritfoto.apps.ave E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv from pid=5471, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:841)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:758)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:684)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
18:26:09.672 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
18:26:09.714 803-1100/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.floritfoto.apps.ave/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser$_13168#0](id:323000009a1,api:0,p:-1,c:803) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
18:26:09.714 13168-14775/com.floritfoto.apps.ave W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x708cee8e80 disconnect failed
18:26:09.729 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:26:09.730 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [Request.cpp]acquire(): Request:: id : 648112, No Resource to set
18:26:09.730 2339-2339/? E/pageboostd: Received HALT command code 2
18:26:09.730 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:26:09.731 803-823/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity$_5471#0](id:323000009a4,api:0,p:-1,c:803) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
18:26:09.731 5471-6304/? W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x708cf88930 disconnect failed
18:26:09.749 13168-14938/com.floritfoto.apps.ave E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv from pid=5471, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:841)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:758)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:684)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
18:26:09.749 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
18:26:09.888 5471-6332/? E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file /data/system/shared_prefs/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.xml
18:26:10.028 727-1236/? E/Sensors: Sensor : Meta event
18:26:10.030 736-17022/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:26:10.228 1452-1452/? E/ExpandableNotifRow: onNotificationUpdated() NSSL is null..
18:26:10.499 736-17015/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
```

As you can see, I get 3 times (why 3??) `Permission Denial: ... requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()`. But my sharing activity not only sets the flag `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, but also this is present in the provider section of the manifest file as `android:grantUriPermissions="true"`.

What is even stranger is that I can share files in the sdcard outside of the app folder or in subfolders (???!!!). For example, I can share the file `/storage/58ED-1620/System Volume Information/WPSettings.dat`. Look at the logcat, even with the same 3 errors, but the file is sent:

```
18:29:50.302 803-824/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [com.floritfoto.apps.ave/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser$_13168#1](id:323000009a8,api:0,p:-1,c:803) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
18:29:50.302 13168-14775/com.floritfoto.apps.ave W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x708d001ec0 disconnect failed
18:29:50.325 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:29:50.328 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:29:50.331 1117-2951/? W/ActivityTaskManager: Tried to set launchTime (0) < mLastActivityLaunchTime (54810092)
18:29:50.333 1117-2951/? W/WindowManager: Execute app transition: mNextAppTransition=TRANSIT_ACTIVITY_OPEN, displayId: 0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.executeAppTransitionForAllDisplay:2586 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.reportResumedActivityLocked:2225 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.completeResumeLocked:5646 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.minimalResumeActivityLocked:1212 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked:1135 
18:29:50.340 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Ignoring intent's EXTRA_TITLE, deprecated in P. You may wish to set a preview title by using EXTRA_TITLE property of the wrapped EXTRA_INTENT.
18:29:50.342 1117-1379/? W/PkgPredictorService: background app without no launcher icon android for.uid: 1000 userId: 0
18:29:50.343 5471-5471/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.android.app.sharestar.ShareStarProvider
18:29:50.387 1117-1135/? E/IntervalStats: Unable to parse usage stats package 1041
18:29:50.387 1117-1135/? E/IntervalStats: Unable to parse usage stats package 1520
18:29:50.387 1117-1135/? E/IntervalStats: Unable to parse usage stats package 1997
18:29:50.436 2498-3360/? W/NearbySharing: Ignore registering DIRECT_SHARE_SERVICE send surface, due to disabled scanning mediums. [CONTEXT service_id=194 ]
18:29:50.436 2498-3360/? W/NearbySharing: NearbySharingService call registerSendSurface returned nonzero status code for calling package com.google.android.gms: STATUS_DISABLED [CONTEXT service_id=194 ]
18:29:50.438 13168-14876/com.floritfoto.apps.ave E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat from pid=5471, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:841)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:758)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:684)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
18:29:50.438 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
18:29:50.466 1117-1145/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{19b8866 u0 com.floritfoto.apps.ave/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5183 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5164 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5570 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:332 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6035 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$dwJG8BAnLlvKNGuDY9U3-haNY4M.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0$SurfaceAnimator:112 
18:29:50.494 5471-5471/? W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by com.android.internal.widget.RecyclerView{9370694 VFED..... ......ID 0,0-1289,1011 #102047e android:id/resolver_list} during layout: running second layout pass
18:29:50.497 13168-14876/com.floritfoto.apps.ave E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat from pid=5471, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:841)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:758)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:684)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
18:29:50.498 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
18:29:50.553 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:29:50.553 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [Request.cpp]acquire(): Request:: id : 648112, No Resource to set
18:29:50.553 736-758/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:29:50.554 803-1997/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity$_5471#0](id:323000009a9,api:0,p:-1,c:803) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
18:29:50.554 5471-6304/? W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x708cf6ac50 disconnect failed
18:29:50.557 2339-2339/? E/pageboostd: Received HALT command code 2
18:29:50.569 13168-14876/com.floritfoto.apps.ave E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat from pid=5471, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:841)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.semEnforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:758)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:684)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:239)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:106)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
18:29:50.569 5471-5471/? W/ChooserActivity: Could not load (content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/System%20Volume%20Information/WPSettings.dat) thumbnail/name for preview. If desired, consider using Intent#createChooser to launch the ChooserActivity, and set your Intent's clipData and flags in accordance with that method's documentation
18:29:50.703 5471-6332/? E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file /data/system/shared_prefs/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.xml
18:29:50.725 727-1236/? E/Sensors: Sensor : Meta event
18:29:50.853 736-17345/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
18:29:50.919 1452-1452/? E/ExpandableNotifRow: onNotificationUpdated() NSSL is null..
18:29:51.329 736-17338/? E/HYPER-HAL: [HandlerSysfs.cpp]doResourceHandling(): Couldn't Open Sysfs - /sys/power/cstate_control
```

I fail to see anything really different between the two logcats!

I have no idea why this began happening in Android 11. What am I doing wrong? Has this something to do with Scoped Storage? Should I migrate to Scoped Storage?

This is the file sharing method:

```
public static void sharefile(Context context, String calledfrom, String filename) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (new SearchOut()).getUriFromFile(context, calledfrom, new File(filename)));
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, FName.file(filename));
    sharingIntent.setType((new FileChooser()).getMimeType(filename));
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, filename));
}
```

EDIT: In the above, the `getUriFromFile` method is essentially the usual one for Android >=7: `FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, auth + ".provider", file);`.

This is my provider data in the manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

and this is my `provider_paths.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <root-path name="root" path="." />
 </paths>
```

Comment: `(new SearchOut()).getUriFromFile(context` We have no idea how you build up an uri or which provider you would use for that. Most relevant info is missing. Nor did you tell its value.

Comment: @blackapps: Sorry, I missed that. It is the usual way for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N` given by `FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, auth + ".provider", file);`

Comment: You still did not tell the value you got for that uri.

Comment: @blackapps: That is in the logcat above: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv`

Comment: So, `uri` is content://com.floritfoto.apps.ave.provider/root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv, while `uri.getPath()` gives /root/storage/58ED-1620/Android/data/com.floritfoto.apps.ave/ornitologia/MyTracks/ave_140321_103008.csv. The `root/` thing is actually introduced by the `name` field in `provider_paths.xml`.

Comment: <root-path is not documented with FileProvider. Normally FileProvider cannot serve from a removable micro sd card. With the undocumented root path you could however. I used to use it too. But apparently google does not want us to do that so it does not work anymore on Android 11. Does it still work on 10? I forgot. Download the old FileProvider.java and you can still use it or extend ContenrProvider then you can serve what you want.

Comment: So what is missing in your post is that you did not tell us you used that undocumented root-path.

Comment: Yes, it worked in Android 10, even in the same device before the upgrade. Ok then, how do I point to that folder in the provider_paths.xml? I tried: `<external-files-path name="files" path="/" />` and `<external-files-path name="files2" path="." />` and `<external-files-path name="files2" path="ornitologia/" />`, and none works.

Comment: "Funny thing" is that I can share files everywhere in the removable sdcard except the ones in the own app folder. :( Could you please point me to a link to "extend ContenrProvider then I can serve what I want"?

Comment: ...or, alternatively, which old FileProvider.java file should I get?

Comment: @blackapps: I created a `uri` by hand without `FileProvider` and using a `Uri.Builder()` (to avoid the `root/` thing), but I still have the same `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial` error.

Comment: Take the .java file of Android 10 if you are sure that it supports root-path. Further i have no links as you can google all.

Comment: `Ok then, how do I point to that folder in the provider_paths.xml? ` Sigh... FileProvider does not serve from micro sd card. That root-path was undocumented and now out.

Comment: I downloaded the FileProvider.java file from 2018: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/a9ac247af2afd4115c3eb6d16c05bc92737d6305/compat/src/main/java/androidx/core/content/FileProvider.java, placed it as MyFileProvider.java, Changed FileProvider call with MyFileProvider, and problem persists. I tried changing the manifest file with `<provider android:name=".MyFileProvider"`, and problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a true solution, but a silly workaround. Sorry.

It seems that in Android 11 we cannot share files from the app own files in the external removable micro sdcard storage through FileProvider: the trick

```
<root-path name="root" path="." />
```

in the provider paths .xml file does not work anymore for the own app's folder in the removable storage (thanks @blackapps !). (Yet, it still works for the other folders in the removable storage, besides the ones in Android/data and Android/obb).

So my coward workaround is to copy the file to share into the app's Cache folder in the main storage `ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(context)[0]`, and share the file from there. When the app closes, I remove this file from cache. :/